# How to filter by an array in AngularJs ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am using ng-repeat to display my data. That is working fine.

One of the data fields in my ng-repeat result set is an array of items.
`Example: {x:1, y:[2,3,4]}` 
I would like to filter by data by data in the array. I can easily filter by the non array data, but I am having trouble when I try to filer by looking inisde in the array.

Here is my markup
 `ng-repeat = "con in cons | filter: usrSingle.username in con.conPlayerList"`

(edited markup to match my example better `ng-repeat = "con in cons | filter: '3' in con.y"` )

usrSingle is a scope in this controller I can access. I don't get any errors and I can't seem to find examples of this.

More code was requested and here it is below. I forgot to mention this is a MEAN app. I have MongoDB serving the data. I use a REST API for my data calls.

(EDIT) code from the angular module:

```
// call to the api for data
app.factory('usrService', function ($resource) {
return $resource('/api/users', {});
});
// factory to hold user data between controllers
app.factory('usrTracker', function () {
var vUsrProfile = {
    usrSingle: 'usrSingle'
};
return {
    getProperty: function () {
        return vUsrProfile;
    },
    setProperty: function (value) {
        vUsrProfile = value;
    }
};
});
// angular controller
app.controller('usrPageController', function ($scope, usrTracker, conService, postService) {

var usrSingle = usrTracker.getProperty();
$scope.usrSingle = usrSingle;
$scope.cons = conService.query();
$scope.posts = postService.query();
});
```

(FINAL EDIT) The answer marked for this is a good solution. But I went another direction. I used the mongoDB $unwind aggregation to explode my data, like below.

code from API file:

```
// get
.get(function (req, res) {
// unwind on the conPlayerList array field
Con.aggregate([{ $unwind: "$conPlayerList" }], function (err, cons) {
return res.json(cons);
});
})
```

Then I filtered on the user I was looking for. Changing the HTML Angular markup to this

`ng-repeat="con in cons | filter:{conPlayerList:usrSingle.username}"`

to match my example better, by removing my specific code, it would be:

`ng-repeat="con in cons | filter: {y:'3'} "`

Comment: You are probably better off writing your own filter function. Consider using a helper library such as lodash (underscore).

Comment: Can you please provide more code so it becomes easy to come up with different solutions to your problem. You might not need to use filters at all.

Comment: I think this needs its own separate filter. I can do that but I was wondering if there was a way to look inside an array that is returned by the ng-repeat command. It seems highly likely that data in a ng-repeat would have fields that are arrays.

Comment: there is no view syntax that will do this without a filter function

Comment: I am new to Angular so I want to make sure I am not missing something simple. The filter functions are a great option for dealing with these types of problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Angular's built in [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) logic on the array, BUT bear in mind this is not an exact match and will match against an array entry of 300 if `usrSingle` is set to 3, see example in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/mk73kwoL/).

```
<div ng-repeat = "con in cons | filter:{y:usrSingle} ">...</div>
```

To match exactly against array elements you can use `filter:` and a predicate function on the controller i.e.

Controller ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/dqhq2mk0/)):

```
app.controller('usrPageController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.filterFn = filterFn;
  $scope.usrSingle = 3;
  $scope.cons = [
      {x:0, y:[1,2,3]},
      {x:1, y:[2,3,4]},
      {x:2, y:[3,4,5]},
      {x:3, y:[4,5,6]},
      {x:4, y:[5,6,7]}
  ];

  function filterFn(con){
    return con.y.indexOf($scope.usrSingle) > -1;
  }
});
```

View:

```
<div ng-repeat = "con in cons | filter:filterFn">...</div>
```

Alternatively you can create a custom filter which can be reused elsewhere in your app and pass `usrSingle` in as a parameter:

Filter ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/db7othLs/)):

```
app.filter('customFilter', function() {
  return function(input, value) {
    var result = [];
    input.forEach(function(item){
        if(item.y.indexOf(value) > -1){
            result.push(item);
        }
    });
    return result;
  };
});
```

View:

```
<div ng-repeat = "con in cons | customFilter:usrSingle">...</div>
```

Comment: This is a great workaround but not the answer I am looking for. It sounds like the only way to filter at point is to use a custom function. I tested your function with my code and the controller function worked great. I will stick with my MongoDB unwind for the moment but I appreciate your answer and detail. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! Ah I understand better your question - updated answer with an additional example you might find useful.

Comment: @sheilak can you help me with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53700568/angularjs-custom-filter-to-check-for-values-inside-a-data-array)