# angularjs custom filter to check for values inside a data array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-filter

I have two filters which filter the data according to the queue key in the data.
Here is my code :

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  // Data object
  $scope.servers = [{
      name: 'ServerA',
      queue: '111'
    },
    {
      name: 'Server7',
      queue: '111'
    },
    {
      name: 'Server2',
      queue: '456'
    },
    {
      name: 'ServerB',
      queue: '456'
    },
  ];

  // Filter defaults
  $scope.Filter = new Object();
  $scope.Filter.queue = {
    'PAV': '111',
    'UAT': '456'
  };

});

// Global search filter
app.filter('searchFilter', function($filter) {
  return function(items, searchfilter) {
    var isSearchFilterEmpty = true;
    angular.forEach(searchfilter, function(searchstring) {
      if (searchstring != null && searchstring != "") {
        isSearchFilterEmpty = false;
      }
    });
    if (!isSearchFilterEmpty) {
      var result = [];
      angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
        var isFound = false;
        angular.forEach(item, function(term, key) {
          if (term != null && !isFound) {
            term = term.toString();
            term = term.toLowerCase();
            angular.forEach(searchfilter, function(searchstring) {
              searchstring = searchstring.toLowerCase();
              if (searchstring != "" && term.indexOf(searchstring) != -1 && !isFound) {
                result.push(item);
                isFound = true;
              }
            });
          }
        });
      });
      return result;
    } else {
      return items;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="mainController">
    <label>show 111</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Filter.queue.PAV" ng-true-value='"111"' ng-false-value='"!111"' />&nbsp;
    <label>show 456</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Filter.queue.UAT" ng-true-value='"456"' ng-false-value='"!456"' />&nbsp;

    <hr />

    <table width="100%" cellpadding="5">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>

        <th>Queue</th>

      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="server in servers | searchFilter:Filter.queue">
        <td>{{server.name}}</td>

        <td>{{server.queue}}</td>

      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

the filters work perfectly.

But if I have the data like this where the queue is inside an array:

```
$scope.servers = [
    {name:'ServerA', queuearr:[{'queue' :'111'}]},
    {name:'Server7', queuearr:[{'queue' :'111'}]},
    {name:'Server2', queuearr:[{'queue' :'456'}]},
    {name:'ServerB', queuearr:[{'queue' :'456'}]},
];
```

> note : there can be multiple objects in the queuerr like
>   this:`[{queue :'111'},{queue :'278'}]`

How do I alter my current code so that the control goes inside the queuerr array and match the queue and return the result accordingly?

Comment: What is the possible value of `searchfilter`? Maybe easier to answer the question if you include what you want to do with the data types instead of only providing the code and have us reverse engineer from your code what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: If I understand this correctly you want to see if the values of  $scope.Filter.queue are in $scope.servers queue and get the corresponding server name?

Comment: @hmr if you do console.log(searchfilter) the output is {
  "PAV": "111",
  "UAT": "456"
}

Comment: Do the keys `PAV` and `UAT` have any meaning? Could you please update the question with what it is you want to do?

Comment: @AlexG i want to see if values of $scope.Filter.queue are in $scope.servers queuearr

Comment: @HMR earlier i did ng-model="Filter.queue.111" in the html but it gave an error so instead I used ng-model="Filter.queue.PAV" just to pass the value into the controller. please check the working demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have some conditions to change in the `Angular.forEach` take a look at the solution.

ServerB shows up in both searchs

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  // Data object
  $scope.servers = [{
      name: 'ServerA',
      queue: '111'
    },
    {
      name: 'Server7',
      queue: '111'
    },
    {
      name: 'Server2',
      queue: '456'
    },
    {
      name: 'ServerB',
      queue: '456',
      queuearr: [{
        queue: '456'
      }, {
        queue: '111'
      }]
    },
  ];

  // Filter defaults
  $scope.Filter = new Object();
  $scope.Filter.queue = {
    'PAV': '111',
    'UAT': '456'
  };

});

// Global search filter
app.filter('searchFilter', function($filter) {
  return function(items, searchfilter) {
    var isSearchFilterEmpty = true;
    angular.forEach(searchfilter, function(searchstring) {
      if (searchstring != null && searchstring != "") {
        isSearchFilterEmpty = false;
      }
    });
    if (!isSearchFilterEmpty) {
      var result = [];
      angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
        var isFound = false;
        angular.forEach(item, function(term, key) {
          // change here to check for arrays
          if (term || Array.isArray(term) && !isFound) {
            // use JSON.stringify here
            term = JSON.stringify(term);
            term = term.toLowerCase();
            angular.forEach(searchfilter, function(searchstring) {
              searchstring = searchstring.toLowerCase();

              if (searchstring != "" && term.indexOf(searchstring) != -1 && !isFound) {
                result.push(item);
                isFound = true;
              }
            });
          }
        });
      });
      return result;
    } else {
      return items;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="mainController">
    <label>show 111</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Filter.queue.PAV" ng-true-value='"111"' ng-false-value='"!111"' />&nbsp;
    <label>show 456</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Filter.queue.UAT" ng-true-value='"456"' ng-false-value='"!456"' />&nbsp;

    <hr />

    <table width="100%" cellpadding="5">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>

        <th>Queue</th>

      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="server in servers | searchFilter:Filter.queue">
        <td>{{server.name}}</td>

        <td>{{server.queue}}</td>

      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is perfect. this one will always work. got to learn from you how useful JSON.stringify can be.  Thank you so much :)

Comment: please take a look at my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894075/angularjs-filter-based-on-matching-values-in-nested-array)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it like this. It is not clear what it is exactly what you want to do because your code is overly complicated and badly aligned.

```
app.filter('searchFilter',function($filter) {
  return function(items, searchfilter) {
      const terms = Object.values(searchfilter).map(
          (val)=>val.toLowerCase(),
      );
      return items.filter((item) =>
          item.queuearr.some((q) => terms.includes(q.queue.toLowerCase())),
      );
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind effort to help me

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter $scope.servers with the values of the queue you can try this. Hope this helps.

```js
const servers = [
    {name:'ServerA', queuearr:[{'queue' :'111'}]},
    {name:'Server7', queuearr:[{'queue' :'111'}]},
    {name:'Server2', queuearr:[{'queue' :'456'}]},
    {name:'ServerB', queuearr:[{'queue' :'456'}]},
];

const itemsToCheck = { 'PAV':'111', 'UAT':'426' };

const filter = (arr, itemsToCheck) => arr.filter((item) => {

    for (let v of Object.values(itemsToCheck)) {

        const found = item.queuearr.find(({ queue }) => queue === v);

        if (found) return true;
    }

    return false;
});

console.log(filter(servers, itemsToCheck));
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind effort to help me

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding another forEach loop to go through the `queuearr` when `queue` is inside an array:

```js
var app =angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    // Data object
   $scope.servers = [
    {name:'ServerA', queuearr:[{'queue' :'111'},{'queue' :'456'}]},
    {name:'Server7', queuearr:[{'queue' :'111'}]},
    {name:'Server2', queuearr:[{'queue' :'456'}]},
    {name:'ServerB', queuearr:[{'queue' :'456'}]},
];

    // Filter defaults
    $scope.Filter = new Object();
    $scope.Filter.queue = {'PAV':'111',
                            'UAT':'456'
                        };
   
});

// Global search filter
app.filter('searchFilter',function($filter) {
        return function(items,searchfilter) {
//console.log(items);
             var isSearchFilterEmpty = true;
              angular.forEach(searchfilter, function(searchstring) {   
                  if(searchstring !=null && searchstring !=""){
                      isSearchFilterEmpty= false;
                  }
              });
        if(!isSearchFilterEmpty){
                var result = [];  
                angular.forEach(items, function(item) {  

                    var isFound = false;
                     angular.forEach(item.queuearr, function(z) {
//console.log(item.queue);     
      angular.forEach(z, function(term,key) {
//console.log(z);
//console.log(item.queue);                         
                         if(term != null &&  !isFound){
                             term = term.toString();
                             term = term.toLowerCase();
                                angular.forEach(searchfilter, function(searchstring) {  
//console.log(searchfilter);    
                                    searchstring = searchstring.toLowerCase();
                                    if(searchstring !="" && term.indexOf(searchstring) !=-1 && !isFound){
                                       result.push(item);
                                        isFound = true;
                                    }
                                });

                         }
                            });
 });
                       });
            return result;
        }else{
        return items;
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <div  ng-controller="mainController">
        <label>show 111</label>
        <input  type="checkbox" ng-model="Filter.queue.PAV" ng-true-value='"111"'  ng-false-value='""' />&nbsp;
        <label>show 456</label>
        <input  type="checkbox" ng-model="Filter.queue.UAT" ng-true-value='"456"'  ng-false-value='""' />&nbsp;
      
        <hr />
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="5">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
               
               
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="server in servers | searchFilter:Filter.queue">
                <td>{{server.name}}</td>
               
               
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now it's working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your snippet as per your given array. Its working fine as per your need.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  // Data object
  /*
  $scope.servers = [{
      name: 'ServerA',
      queue: '111'
    },
    {
      name: 'Server7',
      queue: '111'
    },
    {
      name: 'Server2',
      queue: '456'
    },
    {
      name: 'ServerB',
      queue: '456'
    },
  ];
  */
  $scope.servers = [
    {name:'ServerA', queuearr:[{'queue' :'111'}]},
    {name:'Server7', queuearr:[{'queue' :'111'}]},
    {name:'Server2', queuearr:[{'queue' :'456'}]},
    {name:'ServerB', queuearr:[{'queue' :'456'}]},
];

  // Filter defaults
  $scope.Filter = new Object();
  $scope.Filter.queue = {
    'PAV': '111',
    'UAT': '456'
  };

});

// Global search filter
app.filter('searchFilter', function($filter) {
  return function(items, searchfilter) {
    var isSearchFilterEmpty = true;
    angular.forEach(searchfilter, function(searchstring) {
      if (searchstring != null && searchstring != "") {
        isSearchFilterEmpty = false;
      }
    });
    if (!isSearchFilterEmpty) {
      var result = [];
      angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
        var isFound = false;
        angular.forEach(item.queuearr, function(term, key) {
          if (term.queue != null && !isFound) {
            term.queue = term.queue.toString();
            term.queue = term.queue.toLowerCase();
            angular.forEach(searchfilter, function(searchstring) {
              searchstring = searchstring.toLowerCase();
              if (searchstring != "" && 
              term.queue.indexOf(searchstring) != -1 &&
              !isFound) {
                result.push(item);
                isFound = true;
              }
            });
          }
        });
      });
      return result;
    } else {
      return items;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="mainController">
    <label>show 111</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Filter.queue.PAV" ng-true-value='"111"' ng-false-value='"!111"' />&nbsp;
    <label>show 456</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Filter.queue.UAT" ng-true-value='"456"' ng-false-value='"!456"' />&nbsp;

    <hr />

    <table width="100%" cellpadding="5">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>

        <th>Queue</th>

      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="server in servers | searchFilter:Filter.queue">
        <td>{{server.name}}</td>

        <td>{{server.queuearr[0].queue}}</td>

      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check my answer. Thanks for your kind effort to help me.

Comment: Yes checked but i haven't add another for each.it can also be work with same codebase. Check my solution correctly.

Comment: yea going to implement your solution :)

Comment: this solution does not check multiple values in the array

Comment: @ppollono but he haven't given in provided array.

Comment: read in the question "note : there can be multiple objects in the queuerr like this:[{queue :'111'},{queue :'278'}]"